# How can I make a div have a newspaper background?

Tags: html, css

I see a lot of websites nowadays with backgrounds that are clearly more than just random pictures, images that were specifically made to serve as background images such as chalkboards or clipboards.  I have a div element that is currently just white in it's background.  Does anyone know how I could make it a newspaper type background such that the text I put on it fits in nicely with the Newspaper?.  Btw yes I know how to make something a background image

```
#divOfInterest{
  background-image:url('theUrlOfTheImage')
}
```

but Idk if that would be different for the template type background I am looking for.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/


this link will help you use `background-size` and `background-position`

Comment: Can you show any image as expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 #divOfInterest{
     background: url("theUrlOfTheImage");
     background-size: cover;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add background image to particular div then use

```
.classNameOfDiv {
  background: url("path-of-image") center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is helpful to you

```css
div { height:500px; width:500px;  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://previews.123rf.com/images/eyematrix/eyematrix1210/eyematrix121000010/15910762-Black-and-white-repeating-torn-newspaper-background-Stock-Vector.jpg") repeat scroll center center / cover ; }
```

```html
<div clas="cont_div"></div>
```